# How to load specific fields of data from an ArrayList to certain JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield, jcombobox

[image]

I am working on an assignment that requires us to load data from a .csv file to an `ArrayList`. The first column of the .csv file contains ship names, which has to go in a `JComboBox`. When the user clicks on a specific ship from the `JComboBox`, corresponding information about the ship showed be shown into `JTextField`s. This is the algorithm we were given about as how we should do this in a method name `itemStateChanged`:

1. Extract the ship name from selected item of the options from the pull down list.
2. REPEAT for each ship in the ship list where full data is stored.
3. IF ship name is the same as the selected ship name
4. fill all text fields with the information the ship
5. exit REPEAT
6. END IF
7. END REPEAT

So far, I have been able to load the data from the .csv file to an `ArrayList`. I have also been able to do step 1 of the algorithm. What I don't know is how to go about repeating this for every ship (step 2). I also do not know how to fill up the text fields with corresponding data of the selected ship.

This is my instantiation of the `JTextField`s:

```java
public class ShipGUI extends JFrame{
    private int win_width = 650;
    private int win_Height = 240;
    
    private int gridRows = 3;
    private int gridCols = 2;
    JComboBox SelectShipBox;
    JTextField nameText = new JTextField();
    JTextField flagText = new JTextField();
    JTextField yearText = new JTextField();
    JTextField beamText = new JTextField();
    JTextField draftText = new JTextField();
    JTextField lengthText = new JTextField();
```

This is my code for the `itemStateChanged` method so far:

```java
SelectShipBox = new JComboBox();
SelectShipBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        String select = (String)ie.getItem();
    }});
        
String[] templist = {"Green Acres Afloat","Supnik","Her Majesty's Glory","Sulaco",
                     "Nostromos", "Flying Dutchmen", "Enterprize", "Black Peral", 
                     "PT109", "Titanic", "IronSides", "Nautilus","El Vaquero","Machu 
                      Picchu Skiff", "Folgers Best"};
SelectShipBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(templist));
```

Attached in this post is an image of what the final output should look like.

### Edit

This is the data that the .csv file contains:

```
Supnik,Russia,1911,64,16,38
Her Majesty's Glory,UK,1945,117,29,68
Sulaco,USA,1975,45,11,31
Nostromos,USA,1914,194,49,101
Flying Dutchmen,Tortuga,1912,69,17,36
Enterprize,USSF,1997,125,31,65
Black Peral,Barbados,1925,196,49,106
PT109,USN,1933,151,38,77
Titanic,UK,1995,188,47,97
IronSides,USA,1907,126,32,69
Nautilus,no flag,1886,127,32,68
El Vaquero,Argentina,1986,91,23,51
Machu Picchu Skiff,Peru,2004,135,34,76
Folgers Best,Columbia,1959,197,49,108
```

Comment: Yes, the corresponding information comes from the .csv file. Could you please tell me how do I check whether the event is a SELECT event in the itemStateChanged method?

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the line from the CSV file that contains data for the ship named _Sulaco_. Also, I suggest that you visit this Web page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: I have edited and posted everything that the .csv file contains. And I will check the page out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a class to store the data for a single ship.

```java
public class ShipInfo {
    private String shipName;
    private String countryOfRegistration;
    private int yearOfConstruction;
    private int lengthAtWaterline;
    private int draftAtWaterline;
    private int beamAtWaterline;

    public ShipInfo(String name,
                    String country,
                    int year,
                    int length,
                    int draft,
                    int beam) {
        setShipName(name);
        setCountryOfRegistration(country);
        setYearOfConstruction(year);
        setLengthAtWaterline(length);
        setDraftAtWaterline(draft);
        setBeamAtWaterline(beam);
    }

    public String getShipName() {
        return shipName;
    }

    public String getCountryOfRegistration() {
        return countryOfRegistration;
    }

    public int getYearOfConstruction() {
        return yearOfConstruction;
    }

    public int getLengthAtWaterline() {
        return lengthAtWaterline;
    }

    public int getDraftAtWaterline() {
        return draftAtWaterline;
    }

    public int getBeamAtWaterline() {
        return beamAtWaterline;
    }

    public void setShipName(String name) {
        if (name != null  &&  !name.isEmpty()) {
            shipName = name;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null or empty ship name.");
        }
    }

    public void setCountryOfRegistration(String country) {
        if (country != null  &&  !country.isEmpty()) {
            countryOfRegistration = country;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null or empty country of registration.");
        }
    }

    public void setYearOfConstruction(int year) {
        if (year > 0) {
            yearOfConstruction = year;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative year of construction.");
        }
    }

    public void setLengthAtWaterline(int length) {
        if (length > 0) {
            lengthAtWaterline = length;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative length at waterline.");
        }
    }

    public void setDraftAtWaterline(int draft) {
        if (draft > 0) {
            draftAtWaterline = draft;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative draft at waterline.");
        }
    }

    public void setBeamAtWaterline(int beam) {
        if (beam > 0) {
            beamAtWaterline = beam;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative beam at waterline.");
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean isEqual = false;
        if (obj instanceof ShipInfo) {
            ShipInfo otherShip = (ShipInfo) obj;
            isEqual = shipName.equals(otherShip.shipName)  &&
                      countryOfRegistration.equals(otherShip.countryOfRegistration)  &&
                      yearOfConstruction == otherShip.yearOfConstruction;
        }
        return isEqual;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return shipName.hashCode() + countryOfRegistration.hashCode() + yearOfConstruction;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return shipName;
    }
}
```

The `ShipInfo` class contains a single data member for each separate data. The `equals` and `hashCode` methods aren't really necessary for your GUI application, however the `toString` method is since `JComboBox` calls that method to display its list of items as well as the selected item. Hence method `toString` returns only the ship name.

Here is the GUI application code.
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShipsGui implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
    private static final String  ADD_SHIP = "Add Ship";
    private static final String  CLEAR = "Clear";
    private static final String  QUIT = "Quit";

    private JComboBox<ShipInfo> shipsCombo;
    private JFrame  frame;
    JTextField  beamText;
    JTextField  draftText;
    JTextField  flagText;
    JTextField  lengthText;
    JTextField  nameText;
    JTextField  yearText;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String actionCommand = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case ADD_SHIP:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              "Not yet implemented.",
                                              actionCommand,
                                              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;
            case CLEAR:
                clearAll();
                break;
            case QUIT:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ItemListener
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
        if (itemEvent.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Object obj = itemEvent.getItem();
            if (obj instanceof ShipInfo) {
                ShipInfo shipInfo = (ShipInfo) obj;
                nameText.setText(shipInfo.getShipName());
                flagText.setText(shipInfo.getCountryOfRegistration());
                beamText.setText(getIntText(shipInfo.getBeamAtWaterline()));
                draftText.setText(getIntText(shipInfo.getDraftAtWaterline()));
                lengthText.setText(getIntText(shipInfo.getLengthAtWaterline()));
                yearText.setText(getIntText(shipInfo.getYearOfConstruction()));
            }
        }
    }

    private void addColumnSpacer(JPanel form, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        addLabelToForm(form, "                    ", gbc);
    }

    private void addLabelToForm(JPanel form, String text, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        int anchor = gbc.anchor;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        form.add(label, gbc);
        gbc.anchor = anchor;
    }

    private void clearAll() {
        shipsCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        beamText.setText("");
        draftText.setText("");
        flagText.setText("");
        lengthText.setText("");
        nameText.setText("");
        yearText.setText("");
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() throws IOException {
        frame = new JFrame("Shipping News");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        shipsCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(CLEAR));
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(QUIT));
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(ADD_SHIP));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        form.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Initialize 'GridBagConstraints'.
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 2;
        gbc.insets.left = 2;
        gbc.insets.right = 2;
        gbc.insets.top = 2;

        // First row.
        addLabelToForm(form, "Ship Name:", gbc);
        nameText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        form.add(nameText, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        addColumnSpacer(form, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        addLabelToForm(form, "Length at waterline:", gbc);
        lengthText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        form.add(lengthText, gbc);

        // Second row.
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        addLabelToForm(form, "Country of Registration:", gbc);
        flagText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        form.add(flagText, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        addColumnSpacer(form, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        addLabelToForm(form, "Draft at waterline:", gbc);
        draftText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        form.add(draftText, gbc);

        // Third row.
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        addLabelToForm(form, "Year of Construction:", gbc);
        yearText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        form.add(yearText, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        addColumnSpacer(form, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        addLabelToForm(form, "Beam at waterline:", gbc);
        beamText = getTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        form.add(beamText, gbc);
        return form;
    }

    private JPanel createHeader() throws IOException {
        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        Icon ico = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ship.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Select a ship", ico, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        header.add(label);
        DefaultComboBoxModel<ShipInfo> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(getShips());
        shipsCombo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        shipsCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1); // No initial selection.
        shipsCombo.addItemListener(this);
        header.add(shipsCombo);
        return header;
    }

    private String getIntText(int anInt) {
        return String.valueOf(anInt);
    }

    private JTextField getTextField() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        return textField;
    }

    private ShipInfo[] getShips() throws IOException {
        List<ShipInfo> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("shipinfo.csv");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] flds = line.split(",");
                ShipInfo shipInfo = new ShipInfo(flds[0],
                                                 flds[1],
                                                 Integer.parseInt(flds[2]),
                                                 Integer.parseInt(flds[3]),
                                                 Integer.parseInt(flds[4]),
                                                 Integer.parseInt(flds[5]));
                lst.add(shipInfo);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String slaf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(slaf);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException |
               IllegalAccessException |
               InstantiationException |
               UnsupportedLookAndFeelException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        final ShipsGui gui = new ShipsGui();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                gui.createAndDisplayGui();
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`shipsCombo` displays a list of `ShipInfo` objects. The list is obtained from the CSV file. Method `getShips` reads the file, line by line. A `ShipInfo` object is created from the data in a single line of the file. An array is created that contains all the `ShipInfo` objects and that array is used to create the model for `shipsCombo`. Note that method `getShips` uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

The default [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for [the [content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) of] `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. The top component is `shipsCombo` and a `JLabel`. The `JLabel` contains both text and an icon. The center component are all the `JTextField`s that display the details of the selected ship in `shipsCombo`. And in the bottom component are the `JButton`s.

Note that I got the code for centering the text in `JTextField` from the answer to the following *stackoverflow* question:

[How do I center a JTextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507639/how-do-i-center-a-jtextfield)

When the selected item in `shipsCombo` changes, method `itemStateChanged` is called. The selected item is an instance of class `ShipInfo`. The details are extracted from the selected item and displayed in the appropriate `JTextField`s.

When any one of the `JButton`s are clicked, method `actionPerformed` is called. I did not want to guess what button *Add Ship* should do so the above code simply displays a message saying that the button action is not yet implemented.

This is a screen capture of the running app on my Windows 10 computer with JDK 17.

[image: screen capture of running app]